# electron install error : Generated checksum for "electron-v2.0.2-win32-x64.zip" did not match expected checksum

Tags: npm, electron, npm-install, electron-builder, local-node-modules

I want to install latest electron version in my existing angular application.So I followed npm command to install it.
Command : `npm i electron@latest`

**Expected Behavior**
Electron should installed successfully.

**Actual Behavior**
So, Whenever I tried to install electron, after downloading zip file and SAMSUN.txt file , it is throwing below error....

```
Error: Generated checksum for "electron-v2.0.2-win32-x64.zip" did not match expected checksum.
at ChecksumMismatchError.ErrorWithFilename (E:\CityLawElectron\node_modules\electron-download\node_modules\sumchecker\build.js:41:124)
at new ChecksumMismatchError (E:\CityLawElectron\node_modules\electron-download\node_modules\sumchecker\build.js:56:133)
at Hash. (E:\CityLawElectron\node_modules\electron-download\node_modules\sumchecker\build.js:203:22)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at Hash.emit (events.js:208:7)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:513:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:507:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
at Hash.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
```

Please note that I have tried to clear my npm cache using `npm cache clean --force` command and tried to install. but it didn't work.

I also tried to install electron globally using `npm i -g electron@latest`, but that approach also didn't work.

Please provide solution as soon as possible because I m really stuck at this problem.

```
Electron Version: 2.0.2
Operating System : windows
node version : 8.11.2
npm version : 6.1.0
Last known working Electron version:
```

Comment: "Please provide solution as soon as possible because I'm really stuck at this problem." I would recommend to avoid that kind of comment if you want people to help you :)

Comment: Looks like you already posted [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13168). You'll likely just to have wait for them to reach out.

Comment: Also having the same issue on Windows 10.

Tried above mentioned ways but not able to get the resolution of it.

Environment detail is as below -
OS : Windows 10
node : 10.15.3
npm: 6.9.0
Electron Packager : 13.1.1

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this issue by using following steps (OS - Windows 10)

1. Delete "**SHASUMS256.txt-x.x.xx**" file from "**C:\Users{{UserName}}.electron**".
2. Delete Cache folder from "**C:\Users{{UserName}}\AppData\Local\electron**".
3. Delete electron from **node_modules** folder.
4. Then install electron globally and locally by using following commands -

   **npm init -y** //Note: The -y flag provides default options automatically

   **npm install electron -g** //install electron globally

   **npm install electron --save-dev --save-exact** //install electron as devdependencies

If you are using typescript then install it as global using below command-

**npm install -g typescript**

Above steps may help you.